# Minimal latex template with left-aligned equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

I have the following minimal latex code on overleaf in an attempt to create a 12pt, 1in margin, letter-size document in Times New roman:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, fleqn, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}

\begin{document}
$$Entropy(\text{D}) = -\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d) \log_{2}p(d) $$
$$Entropy(\text{S}) = p(s+)\Bigg [ -\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d | s+) \log_{2}p(d | s+)\Bigg ] \\
+ p(s-)\Bigg [-\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d | s-) \log_{2}p(d | s-)\Bigg ]$$
\end{document}
```

And I'm trying to simply left align all of the equations and hide equation numbers.

Here is what I have tried without success:

- `fleqn` in document options
- `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`
- `\begin{flalign*}` and `\end{flalign*}`
- `\setlength\mathindent{0pt}`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $$ is not recommended for this very reason. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, 
            margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}  % <----

\begin{document}
    \[
\mathrm{Entropy}(D) = -\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d) \log_{2}p(d) 
    \]
some text?
    \[
\mathrm{Entropy}(S) 
    \begin{multlined}[t][0.5\linewidth]
    = p(s+)\Bigg[-\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d | s+) \log_{2}p(d | s+)\Bigg]    \\
+ p(s-)\Bigg[-\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d | s-) \log_{2}p(d | s-)\Bigg]
    \end{multlined}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Note, in document code is corrected errors in equation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the `align*` environment, the `fleqn` and `alignedleftspaceno` options of `amsmath`, and a `\@mathmargin` of zero.  To break a long equation, insert a `split`.

If you just want equations flush left without alignment points, you can use the `lgather` environment from `mathtools`.

The `fleqn` option should go to `amsmath` or whatever package loads it.  You should only give it to the document class if you are using an AMS class, such as `amsbook`.

It sets equations left, [with an indentation set by `\@mathmargin`.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf)  Setting it to `0pt` gets you flush left.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[fleqn, alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\else
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
  \setmainfont[Scale = 1.0]{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\fi

% Set the left margin used by fleqn to 0pt.
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\@mathmargin0pt\relax}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\Entropy}{Entropy}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \Entropy(\mathrm{D}) &= -\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d) \log_{2}p(d) \\
  \intertext{Oh, and by the way:}
  \begin{split}
  \Entropy(\mathrm{S}) &=
     p(s+)\Bigg [ -\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d | s+) \log_{2}p(d | s+)\Bigg ] \\
     &\hphantom{=} + p(s-)\Bigg [-\sum\limits_{d \in D} p(d | s-) \log_{2}p(d | s-)\Bigg ]
  \end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Equation sample]

I took a few liberties, such as setting the math font to match Times, defining an operator `\Entropy` that works like `\log` or `\sin`, and changing `\text` (which matches the current formatting of the surrounding text) to `\mathrm` (upright letters in math mode).

The alignment of the second line of the split equation is very flexible.  You can for example remove the `\hphantom` to align the `+ with the`=` above, or add more space after it.